# Get Xpath for Element in Python

Tags: python, html

I've been researching this for two days now. There seems to be no simple way of doing this. I can find an element on a page by downloading the html with Selenium and passing it to BeautifulSoup, followed by a search via classes and strings. I want to click on this element after finding it, so I want to pass its Xpath to Selenium. I have no minimal working example, only pseudo code for what I'm hoping to do.

Why is there no function/library that lets me search through the html of a webpage, find an element, and then request it's Xpath? I can do this manually by inspecting the webpage and clicking 'copy Xpath'. I can't find any solutions to this on stackoverflow, so please don't tell me I haven't looked hard enough.

Pseudo-Code:

```
  *parser is BeautifulSoup HTML object*
  for box in parser.find_all('span', class_="icon-type-2"): # find all elements with particular icon
      xpath = box.get_xpath()
```

I'm willing to change my code entirely, as long as I can locate a particular element, and extract it's Xpath. So any other ideas on entirely different libraries are welcome.

Comment: Did you tried something like this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup/